# How to reach value from the response in Karate?

Tags: api, testing, karate

Thanks for your time reading this question! I really appreciate it.
After some api call I receive response like:

```
{
   "version": {
       "1.0.0": {
         "reqId":"1sad2342-3246-vdw2-36nd-12fshuiy65r1"
       }
   }
}
```

I need to def the "reqId" value for integration testing. How can I reach it? Karate treats 1.0.0 as 3 different keys. So, I tried:
Then def requestId = response.version.1.0.0.reqId . I also tried to make it with quotation "1.0.0" or hashtag but nothing worked. Any suggestions?